# If a class depends on a class from another package, does it depend on all other classes in that package?

Tags: java, architecture, dependencies, package

I am currently learning the principles of software design, specifically [Acyclic Dependencies Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/Principles_and_Patterns.pdf) (page 18)

From the example that was given I interpreted it as: when one class in package A depends on a class in package B, then package A depends on all classes in package B as well as their dependencies (transitively)

I know that package A will be dependent on package B. But all of package B's classes that weren't actually depended on - I am not so sure about that. The only way that I think it could cascade as in the example is when the class that was depended on in package B actually has a dependency on some classes in package B which then have dependencies on other packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A package is just a namespace. Dependencies on packages don't exist. You can depend on classes, and these classes are in a package, but that's all. You don't depend on all the classes of a package if you depend on one of them.

Saying that a class or package depends on another package is just a shortcut to say that it depends on at least one class of this package.

Comment: +1: But packaging (i.e., delivering as jars) can lead to something resembling package-level dependency that's a bit more real, and cycles can matter.

Comment: @Don Roby - I never thought about packaging that way. If you use a class within a jar (package) does it then need to compile all classes contained in that jar?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the class in package A (lets call it ClassA) is only dependent on the class in package B (lets call that ClassB) that it uses.

But if ClassB is dependent on ClassBee and ClassBuzz (also in package B) then ClassA will also be dependent on those.

If one class in a package (A) is dependent on one class in another package (B) then A is dependent on B, regardless of whether the class you want to use (say ClassApe) uses any of the classes in package B.

I hope this answers your question and is not overly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I think your last clause about inner dependencies in the other package is rather important as long as the package is supposedly providing minimum of accessibility needed, still striving to function properly. So, this principle, probably, tell to use the whole package, not some of its parts.

But you do not depend on more classes then you use, all of the functionality should remain the same for you in the following package releases with your access to public parts of the package, but its not you who should worry about inner dependencies, but the authors of the package.